# Monthly average, type of purchase, and low vs high in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

**Invoice**

| user_id | month | purchase type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12303 | 12/1/2017 | upload | 10 |
| 12303 | 12/1/2017 | download | 2 |
| 12303 | 01/01/2018 | upload | 10 |
| 12303 | 01/01/2018 | upload | 2.18 |
| 12303 | 01/01/2018 | download | 3 |
| 12304 | 12/01/2017 | upload | 630 |
| 12304 | 12/01/2017 | download | 200 |

**Users**

| user_id | email | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12303 | hank@hotmail.com | 2016-04-02 18:40:50 |
| 12303 | hank@gmail.com | 2017-09-15 13:10:22 |

I need to find the monthly spend by most recent email, count of each upload, and whether or not they spent over $500.

Example of what I'm trying to figure out:

| email | month | purchase count | total spent | segment (over $500) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hank@gmail.com | 12/01/2017 | number | number | Below $500 |
| hank@gmail.com | 01/01/2018 | number | number | Below $500 |

I can't seem to get the email to pull as most recent among everything else. It just associates all the data twice with both emails.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT u.email
     , i.month
     , count(*) AS "purchase count"
     , sum(i.amount) AS "total spent"
     , CASE WHEN sum(i.amount) >= 500 THEN 'Over $500' ELSE 'Below $500' END AS "segment(over $500)"
  FROM users AS u
 INNER JOIN invoice AS i
    ON i.user_id = u.user_id
 GROUP BY u.email, i.month
```

or this if you only want one row per email with the latest month :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.email)
       u.email
     , i.month
     , count(*) AS "purchase count"
     , sum(i.amount) AS "total spent"
     , CASE WHEN sum(i.amount) >= 500 THEN 'Over $500' ELSE 'Below $500' END AS "segment(over $500)"
  FROM users AS u
 INNER JOIN invoice AS i
    ON i.user_id = u.user_id
 GROUP BY u.email, i.month
 ORDER BY u.email, i.month DESC
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4f7f0872ed7059609c53926190b28af2).

Comment: Appreciate the help! This is pretty much the solution I had gotten to but it creates four rows (two for each email). I'm trying to get the query to return only the most recent email (kind of like an update to a record). 

https://imgur.com/a/5pud38t

Comment: Your last comment is not consistent with the example in your question where there are 2 rows for the same email 'hank@gmail.com'. Answer updated according to your last comment.

Comment: Current solution is pulling both emails but I need it to pull the most recent email associated with the user_id and have the rows separated by month. I'm not sure how to articulate this correctly. https://imgur.com/a/LMD9H6o